# Online or free learning resources for Silverlight Styling

Tags: silverlight, xaml, styling

Hy i'm looking for these types of learning resources.

- One that is explaining the basics of
  the Silverlight styling(Basic Terms).
  Or some very simple collection of
  examples,in wich i can learn a lot.
- And one is that is very similar to Silverlight Documentation 
  (ex. what property do you need to set if you want have this modification),except that is more confortable to use.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think that the whole way Silverlight "Styling and templating" is being explained is ludicrous. We're talking about these 2 properties like it's rocket science or something.

There's a massive hype around Silverlight "Styling and templating" when it is in fact a very easy and approachable topic.

The best way you could possibly understand how Silverlight UI works is through the Silverlight UI Designers: Expression Blend and Visual Studio 2010 Silverlight Designer. 
Blend however is much more accommodating to this topic.

> *And one is that is very similar to Silverlight Documentation (ex. what property do you need to set if you want have this modification),except that is more confortable to use.*

You want to know what a property on a control does? Open up Expression Blend and play around with it. Reading a book, watching a webcast or even skimming through MSDN is no substitue for real exprience.

So, download [expression blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/Default.aspx#PageTop), start a new Silverlight project, place a control on the design surface and start fiddling around with it. It's a good way you'll gain real world experience.

Also, Microsoft ships the 2 following sample apps for it's Silverlight controls:

1) Silverlight Framework controls - http://silverlight.net/content/samples/sl2/silverlightcontrols/run/default.html

2) Silverlight SDK + Silverlight Toolkit controls - http://silverlight.net/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html

> *One that is explaining the basics of the Silverlight styling(Basic Terms). Or some very simple collection of examples,in wich i can learn a lot.*

Excellent question. There's a lot that can be said about Styling, Templating and the VisualStateManager. But, Instead of saying it - I'll point you again to Blend.

Please watch theese four following VisualStateManager ["How Do I?" videos](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc643423.aspx) by Steve White. These helped me tremendously when I tried to wrap my brain around VSM and templating.

Comment: The Silverlight SDK sample site i know very well i use nearly every day,for simple tasks it's working very well.I also use Expression Blend,but just as a Designer,maybe there i made a mistake.I will investigate,how else could help my work.I will watch the videos thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

What I've been using are the silverlight.net videos and then the MSDN site for properties of different controls.  Watch the themeing videos on Silverlight.net for sure though.  They're really useful.

One thing to watch out for... if the control is not a part of the standard set of controls (IE they're still not built directly in like the datagird control) when you go to theme them, you will not have any pre-determined values in the "edit current template" option.  You have to go and find an example of their default theme, copy in and then mess with that.

Answer (score 2):

I find the [MSDN documentation on Silverlight 3 control styling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc278068(VS.95).aspx) quite good.

Answer (score 0):

I've just released a creative commons set of styles for Silverlight 4 beta - you can download those and play with them/look through the xaml to get an idea of how styles work

http://www.blackspike.com/site/silverlight/free-silverlight-4-beta-skin